# Babelify transform with globally installed presets

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have multiple modules written with es2015 features. I would like to not have es2015 transform as dependency for every module, but have it installed globally. 
It fails with

`Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory`

Have anyone tried it? Any workaround?

Comment: Globally installed won't do. It needs to be installed locally to the project with `npm install --save-dev`

Answer (score 0):

**Error:** Couldn't find preset "**es2015**" relative to directory to resolve  you need to install the preset

```
npm install  babel-preset-es2015
```

Answer (score 0):

i wrote the .babelrc in this way and it worked.

```
{
"presets":["env","es2015","react"]
}
```